# MXF D10 PAL encoded with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a MXF D10 input that I am trying to encode using FFMPEG. This input is 720x512 but its actual height is 486 (as per mediainfo). I process via FFMPEG and I see black lines at top.

Can FFMPEG interpret MXF D10 correctly ? I realize that many players have problem displaying MXF D10 but the question is does FFMPEG decode this correctly ?

Also, which players would play MXF D10 correctly without black lines at top.

I am using FFMPEG 3.2

Comment: 720x486 indicates a NTSC D1 resolution. Looks like ffmpeg is not reading the crop info. Can you share the file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zKLr6FLohO2yd-8YRhQrDHQYC5cI90g9/view?usp=sharing